# Обработка строковых переменных

Tags: ассемблер, строки

Задание: Ввести строку текста. Проверить, является ли этот текст гиперссылкой в формате «http:\www.abc.ua». Если да, то напечатать сообщение: «Это гиперссылка» в другом случае: «Это не гиперссылка».

Был дан пример работы со строковыми переменными:

```
.model  small
.stack  100h
.data
    string db 80 dup(?)
    promt db 0Dh,0Ah,'Enter link: $'
    ok db 0Dh,0Ah,'This is link$'
    notok db 0Dh,0Ah,'This is not a link! $'
    link db 'http$'
.code 
start:
    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax       ;В АХ-адреса початку сегмента даних
@beg1:
    mov     ah,09h  ;Вивiд запиту на введення пароля
    mov     dx,offset promt ;Адреса запиту
    inc     dx
    int     21h
            ;Введемо пароль
    mov     bx,0        ;iнiцiалiзацiя iндексацiї введення
    ; я бы написал xor bx,bx
    lea si, string
@pass:
    mov     ah,08h  ;Функцiя введення символу в AL без ехо
    int     21h
    cmp     al,13       ;<Enter> ?
    je  @compare    ;Так, на порiвняння
    mov     [si],al
    mov ah,02
    mov     dl,al      ;Запишемо на екран *
    int     21h
    inc     si
    inc     bx    ; увеличиваем счётчик длины
    jmp     @pass

        ;Порiвняння введеного пароля з дiйсним (порiвняння рядкiв)
@compare:
    push    ds      ;Встановити ES на сегмент даних
    pop     es
    lea     si,string   ;DS:SI- початок string
    inc     si
    lea     di,link     ;ES:DI- початок link
    inc     di
    cld             ;DF=0- перегляд вперед
    dec     bx
    mov     cx,bx    ;Встановити лiчильник порiвняння
    repe    cmpsb   ;Порiвнювати, поки CX<>0 i ZF=1 (тобто повторювати
            ;поки символи двох рядкiв спiвпадають, але не бiльш CX раз)
    jne     @err        ;Рядки не рiвнi
            ;Виведення повiдомлення ОК, пiдтверджуючого правильнiсть пароля
    jmp     @end1
@err:
    mov     ah,09h
    mov     dx,offset notok
    inc     dx
    int     21h
    jmp     @beg1   ;Повторити введення пароля
@end1:
    mov     ah,09h
    mov     dx,offset ok
    inc     dx
    int     21h
    jmp     @beg1
    MOV     AH,4ch  ;DOS-функцiя завершення роботи програми    
    INT     21h         ;Виклик переривання DOS
end start
end
```

Я что-то там пыталась переделывать. Например, чтобы подсчитывало длину строки... на этом и заглохло всё((

Answer (score 1):

Так что конкретно нужно-то? Длину строки можете считать прямо при посимвольном вводе, начало же положено в обнулении bx (правда, не помню, меняют ли функции 2 и 8 этот регистр, вроде нет):

```
    mov     bx,0        ;iнiцiалiзацiя iндексацiї введення
    ; я бы написал xor bx,bx
    lea si, string
@pass:
    mov     ah,08h  ;Функцiя введення символу в AL без ехо
    int     21h
    cmp     al,13       ;<Enter> ?
    je  @compare    ;Так, на порiвняння
    mov     [si],al
    mov ah,02
    mov     dl,'*'      ;Запишемо на екран *
    int     21h
    inc     si
    inc     bx    ; увеличиваем счётчик длины
    jmp     @pass
```

Или так:

```
    lea si, string
    mov bx, si
@pass:
    mov     ah,08h  ;Функцiя введення символу в AL без ехо
    int     21h
    cmp     al,13       ;<Enter> ?
    je  @compare    ;Так, на порiвняння
    mov     [si],al
    mov     ah,02
    mov     dl,'*'      ;Запишемо на екран *
    int     21h
    inc     si
    jmp     @pass 
@compare:
    ; длина строки = si-bx
```

**UPD** *Дело было вечером, делать было нечего...*

```
section .data

; ------------------------------------------
; internal data
; ------------------------------------------
ok          db  " - OK", 0Ah
ok_length   equ $-ok

fail        db  " - FAIL", 0Ah
fail_length equ $-fail

http        db  "http://"
http_length equ $-http

; ------------------------------------------
; strings for test
; ------------------------------------------
http1       db  "http://a"   ; FAIL
h1_length   equ $-http1

http2       db  "http://.a"  ; FAIL
h2_length   equ $-http2

http3       db  "http://a."  ; FAIL
h3_length   equ $-http3

http4       db  "http://a.a" ; OK
h4_length   equ $-http4

section .text

; ------------------------------------------
;
; $ nasm -f elf http.asm
; $ gcc http.o
; $ ./a.out
;
; http://a - FAIL
; http://.a - FAIL
; http://a. - FAIL
; http://a.a - OK
;
; ------------------------------------------
global main
main:
    mov esi, http1
    mov ebx, h1_length
    call check_http
    mov esi, http2
    mov ebx, h2_length
    call check_http
    mov esi, http3
    mov ebx, h3_length
    call check_http
    mov esi, http4
    mov ebx, h4_length
    call check_http

    mov eax, 1
    xor ebx, ebx
    int 80h

; ------------------------------------------
; IN: esi = string, ebx = string length
; ------------------------------------------
check_http:
    pushfd
    push es
    push edi
    push esi

    push ds
    pop es

    mov ecx, esi
    mov edx, ebx
    call print

    mov ecx, http_length
    sub ebx, ecx
    jbe check_fail

    mov edi, http
    cld
    rep cmpsb
    jne check_fail

    lodsb
    cmp al, '.'
    je check_fail

    dec ebx
    jz check_fail

    xchg ecx, ebx
    xchg esi, edi
    mov al, '.'
    repne scasb
    jcxz check_fail

    mov ecx, ok
    mov edx, ok_length
    jmp check_print

check_fail:
    mov ecx, fail
    mov edx, fail_length

check_print:
    call print

    pop esi
    pop edi
    pop es
    popfd
    ret

; ------------------------------------------
; IN: ecx = string, edx = string length
; ------------------------------------------
print:
    push eax
    push ebx
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    int 80h
    pop ebx
    pop eax
    ret
```

Answer (score 0):

Класс! Теперь считает!!!)
А не знаете, как еще можно сделать проверку на то, является ли текст гиперссылкой в формате http:\www.abc.ua
Как сделать проверку на совпадение http:\www. - понятно
Но ведь здесь abc.ua могут быть разные символы и их количество.
Возможно ли вообще сделать такую проверку?

```
 .model  small
.stack  100h
.data
    string db 80 dup(?)
    promt db 0Dh,0Ah,'Enter link: $'
    ok db 0Dh,0Ah,'This is link$'
    notok db 0Dh,0Ah,'This is not a link! $'
    link db 'http://www.$'
.code 
start:
    mov ax,@data
    mov ds,ax       ;В АХ-адреса початку сегмента даних
@beg1:
    mov     ah,09h  ;Вивiд запиту на введення пароля
    mov     dx,offset promt ;Адреса запиту
    inc     dx
    int     21h
            ;Введемо пароль
    mov     bx,0        ;iнiцiалiзацiя iндексацiї введення
    ; я бы написал xor bx,bx
    lea si, string
@pass:
    mov     ah,08h  ;Функцiя введення символу в AL без ехо
    int     21h
    cmp     al,13       ;<Enter> ?
    je  @compare    ;Так, на порiвняння
    mov     [si],al
    mov ah,02
    mov     dl,al      ;Запишемо на екран *
    int     21h
    inc     si
    inc     bx    ; увеличиваем счётчик длины
    jmp     @pass

            ;Порiвняння введеного пароля з дiйсним (порiвняння рядкiв)
@compare:
    push    ds      ;Встановити ES на сегмент даних
    pop     es
    lea     si,string   ;DS:SI- початок string
    inc     si
    lea     di,link     ;ES:DI- початок link
    inc     di
    cld             ;DF=0- перегляд вперед

    mov     cx,10    ;Встановити лiчильник порiвняння
    cmp     bx,0
    je      @err
 xor bx,bx
    repe    cmpsb   ;Порiвнювати, поки CX<>0 i ZF=1 (тобто повторювати
            ;поки символи двох рядкiв спiвпадають, але не бiльш CX раз)
    jne     @err        ;Рядки не рiвнi
            ;Виведення повiдомлення ОК, пiдтверджуючого правильнiсть пароля
    jmp     @end1
@err:
    mov     ah,09h
    mov     dx,offset notok
    inc     dx
    int     21h
    jmp     @beg1   ;Повторити введення пароля
@end1:
    mov     bh,[si] ;закидаємо індекс на перший символ
    cmp     bh, '.'
    je      @m1
    jmp     @m2
@m1:
    inc     bx      ;збільшуємо лічильник точок
    cmp     bx, 1
    je      @symb
   ; cmp     bx, 2
   ; je      @symb
    cmp     bx, 2
    ja      @err
    inc     si      ;зсуваємося по символах
    jmp     @end1
@m2:
  ;  cmp     cx,1
  ;  je      @symb
    inc     si      ;зсуваємося по символах
    jmp     @end1
@symb:
    inc     si
    mov     bh, [si]
    cmp     bh,'.'
    je      @err
    cmp     bh,' '
    je      @err
    cmp     bh,'$'
    je      @err
    jmp     @end1
@end2:
    cmp     bx, 2
    je      @end3

@end3:
    mov     ah,09h
    mov     dx,offset ok
    inc     dx
    int     21h
    jmp     @beg1
    MOV     AH,4ch  ;DOS-функцiя завершення роботи програми    
    INT     21h         ;Виклик переривання DOS
end start
end
```

Comment: Думаю, достаточно проверить, что после `http://` (что вообще за `http:\`? и почему в шаблоне `link` содержится `http`, а не `http://`?) 1) есть символы 2) первый символ не точка 3) последний символ строки не точка и 4) точка в строке всё-таки есть.

Comment: А это в процессе испытаний я забыла поменять) Сейчас буду пробовать

Comment: Наваяла...
Но пока каждый раз пишет, что это не гиперссылка. Кажись напутала с метками.

Comment: Обновил ответ :) Не надо пугаться, это не TASM и не MASM, а NASM, и не DOS... Но в принципе - оно же :)

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я сдала)